# How do I create a database on MariaDB server?

Tags: mariadb

My hosting provider shows `Server version: 10.1.44-MariaDB-cll-lve - MariaDB Server` on cPanel.

I'm about to do some dev work locally.

I installed MariaDB on my Windows 10. It went under `C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.4` and I see that it installed itself as a service called MariaDB. Service is running.

I'm asking my question after trying a whole whack of things because I had done this many times using MySQL before this MariaDB thing.

How do I create a database off an sql dump file?

[image: Error running the import command]

Since nothing that I'm trying is working and this is a brand new Maria DB installation , I would rather not talk about how I did this before. Instead, having this MariaDB installation now, what do I do to import this sql file?

Comment: What didn't work when you tried creating the database exactly like you would if you were using MySQL? What errors did you get, etc?

Comment: You do it in the exact same way as you do in mysql. Using mysqlimport, mysql cli, phpmyadmin, mysql workbench...

Comment: Done it many times before. Not sure why MariDB is different.

Comment: I don't recall commands, so I followed https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-import-and-export-databases-in-mysql-or-mariadb

Comment: mysql -u dbwriter -p root < C:/path/to/my/file.sql;

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Comment: Since this is MariaDB and not trad MySQL, let's not focus on what I had been doing. What do I do now?I have an SQL dump and want to import it into a local db. Local db is crated fine (I'm in Maria DB[MyDbName]> )

Comment: I added the error snapshot.

Comment: You are trying to run the `mysql` command, from *within* the MySQL command. Type **exit** then run that same command.

Comment: That throws a bunch of options for running the commands. It just doesn't understand the command.

Comment: Not sure why I'm getting the downvotes. There should be a simple path to follow. After all, this is a fresh MariaDB install and and a new MariaDB dump file. If this is so hard to sort out, then I wonder what a real issue with migrating data would be like. I'll sort it out tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

OK, so this is what we need to do:

Assuming that your database is called MyDB.

- Start command prompt as admin.
- cd C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.4\bin>  // /bin where your MariaDB installation went.
- mysql -u root
- create database MyDB;
- exit;
- mysql -uroot MyDB < C:/where-you-have-the-file/dump-file.sql
- mysql -u root
- use MyDB
- show tables;

Hopefully, you see your schema.

Comment: But this is exactly the same process you would go through if you were using MySQL. Yet several of your comments said that you had done this kind of thing many times with MySQL but it wouldn't work with MariaDB. So what were you doing wrong?